# How to name nested controllers and routes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm working on creating a wiki app from scratch with the following organization:

Main Controller: Wiki
Nested Controller: WikiCategories
Nested Controller: WikiArticles

In my config/routes.rb I have:

```
resource :wiki do
  resources :wiki_categories, :as => :categories
  resources :wiki_articles, :as => :articles
end
```

I've chosen to name the categories and articles controllers as WikiCategories and WikiArticles to differentiate from other category and article controllers that I want to make in the future under a blog nesting.

This gives me the following routes:

```
/wiki/wiki_categories/new
/wiki/wiki_articles/new
```

Is there any way to rewrite the routes to be:

```
/wiki/categories/new
/wiki/articles/new
```

... while still using the WikiCategories and WikiArticles controller names?

Answer (score 4):

> I've chosen to name the categories and articles controllers as WikiCategories and WikiArticles to differentiate from other category and article controllers that I want to make in the future under a blog nesting.

IMO, it seems like you're bucking convention a bit. As discussed in [Controller Namespaces and Routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing), why not do:

```
namespace :wiki do
  resources :categories, :articles
end
```

Which will give you:

```
    wiki_categories GET    /wiki/categories(.:format)              wiki/categories#index
                    POST   /wiki/categories(.:format)              wiki/categories#create
  new_wiki_category GET    /wiki/categories/new(.:format)          wiki/categories#new
 edit_wiki_category GET    /wiki/categories/:id/edit(.:format)     wiki/categories#edit
      wiki_category GET    /wiki/categories/:id(.:format)          wiki/categories#show
                    PATCH  /wiki/categories/:id(.:format)          wiki/categories#update
                    PUT    /wiki/categories/:id(.:format)          wiki/categories#update
                    DELETE /wiki/categories/:id(.:format)          wiki/categories#destroy
      wiki_articles GET    /wiki/articles(.:format)                wiki/articles#index
                    POST   /wiki/articles(.:format)                wiki/articles#create
   new_wiki_article GET    /wiki/articles/new(.:format)            wiki/articles#new
  edit_wiki_article GET    /wiki/articles/:id/edit(.:format)       wiki/articles#edit
       wiki_article GET    /wiki/articles/:id(.:format)            wiki/articles#show
                    PATCH  /wiki/articles/:id(.:format)            wiki/articles#update
                    PUT    /wiki/articles/:id(.:format)            wiki/articles#update
                    DELETE /wiki/articles/:id(.:format)            wiki/articles#destroy
```

Then, create namespaced controllers, something like:

```
app/controllers/wiki/categories.rb

class Wiki::CategoriesController < ApplicationController
  ...
end
```

and

```
app/controllers/wiki/articles.rb

class Wiki::ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  ...
end
```

Comment: Certainly cleaner and elegant solution to the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is by specifying the `controller`, the resource can then be named whichever way you like.

```
resource :wiki do
  resources :categories, controller: 'wiki_categories'
  resources :articles, controller: 'wiki_articles'
end
```

Please see [the guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#specifying-a-controller-to-use) for further information.

Comment: Amazing. Thank you. I was looking through the guide for the right option but couldn't remember what it was called. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `path:` option as follows:

```
resource :wiki do
  resources :wiki_categories, path: 'categories', :as => :categories
  resources :wiki_articles, path: 'articles', :as => :articles
end
```

Which will give you:

```
/wiki/categories/...
/wiki/articles/...
```

See [Translated Paths](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#translated-paths) section of the guides for further details.

Comment: Thanks you! This works but the 'controller' specification is a bit cleaner and was what I was looking for: 

    resources :categories, controller: 'wiki_categories'

Appreciate the help though.